# Hibernate unidirectional many to many does not insert into join table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to implement a unidirectional many to many relationship between 2 tables as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Book")
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="book_name")
private String bookName;

 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "book_author", 
             joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id") }, 
             inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "author_id") })
private List<Author> bookAuthors;
  //getter and setters here
 }
```

My author class is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Author")
public class Author {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="author_name")
private String authorName;

@Column(name="author_description")
private String authorDesc;
//getter setters here
}
```

The code for saving data is as follows (Note that I am invoking save on the book object which is the owning entity):

```
   //create book
    Book book1 = new Book();
    book1.setBookName("Book1");

    //create and set Author info
    Author author1 = new Author();
    author1.setAuthorName("a1");
    author1.setAuthorDesc("a1 description");

    Author author2 = new Author();
    author2.setAuthorName("a2");
    author2.setAuthorDesc("a2 description");

    List<Author> authorsList1 = new ArrayList<Author>();
    authorsList1.add(author1);
    authorsList1.add(author2);
    book1.setBookAuthors(authorsList1);


    //save book
    session.save(book1);
```

This executes the following hibernate code:

```
Hibernate: insert into Book (book_name, category_id, numOfCopies) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Author (author_description, author_name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into Author (author_description, author_name) values (?, ?)
```

When I query the tables, I see data in the Book and Author table but not in the join table i.e. Book_author. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

I referred to the following example:
http://websystique.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-unidirectional-annotation-example/

I even tried changing the code to a bidirectional mapping by adding books into my author class as follows:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="bookAuthors")
private List<Book> books;
```

but still no data gets saved into the join table.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating ManyToMany relationships in JPA or Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203892/updating-manytomany-relationships-in-jpa-or-hibernate)

Comment: No, my question is different. In the question pointed out, save works for the user when saved from the owning entity. However, in my case it does not insert into the join table even when save is invoked from the owning entity.

Comment: Don't know. You should be saving author1 and author2 and posting a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: Found the issue, I had left out the transaction.commit call and so data was not getting inserted into the join table. Thanks very much for your response!